# How to fetch related model in django_tables2 to avoid a lot of queries?

Tags: python, django, django-tables2

I might be missing something simple here. And I simply lack the knowledge or some how-to.
I got two models, one is `site`, the other one is `siteField` and  the most important one - `siteFieldValue`.

My idea is to create a django table (for `site`) that uses the values from `siteFieldValue` as a number in a row, for a specific site, under certain header. The problem is - each site can have 50s of them. That * number of columns specified by `def render_` functions * number of sites equals to a lot of queries and I want to avoid that.

My question is - is it possible to, for example, prefetch all the values for each site (`SiteFieldValue.objects.filter(site=record).first()` somewhere in the `SiteListTable` class), put them into an array and then use them in the `def render_` functions by simply checking the value assigned to a key (id of the field).

Models:

```
class Site(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class SiteField(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class SiteFieldValue(models.Model):
    site = models.ForeignKey(Site, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    field = models.ForeignKey(SiteField, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    value = models.CharField(max_length=500)
```

Table view

```
class SiteListTable(tables.Table):
    name = tables.Column()
    importance = tables.Column(verbose_name='Importance',empty_values=())
    vertical = tables.Column(verbose_name='Vertical',empty_values=())
    #... and many more to come... all values based on siteFieldValue

    def render_importance(self, value, record):
        q = SiteFieldValue.objects.filter(site=record, field=1).first()
        # ^^ I don't want this!! I would want the SiteFieldValue to be prefetched somewhere else for that model and just check the array for field id in here. 
        if (q):
            return q.value
        else:
            return None


    def render_vertical(self, value, record):
        q = SiteFieldValue.objects.filter(site=record, field=2).first()
        # ^^ I don't want this!! I would want the SiteFieldValue to be prefetched somewhere else for that model and just check the array for field id in here. 
        if (q):
            return q.value
        else:
            return None

    class Meta:
        model = Site
        attrs = {
        "class": "table table-striped","thead" : {'class': 'thead-light',}}
        template_name = "django_tables2/bootstrap.html"
        fields = ("name", "importance", "vertical",)
```

Comment: What you have done here is create a through table (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships), which is usually used in a many to many relationship. This means that a site can have many fields, but a field can also have many sites. Is this really what you want? I suspect you actually want a field to have a foreign key to a site, so a site has many fields, but fields have only one site.  Either way, it will make life easier to explicitly set up that relationship in django, so please let us know how the relationships work.

Comment: @SamSparx Yeah, the tables are good imo. There's a number of fields imported from the fixture with certain id's (SiteField), every website has the same ones (these will be the headers [columns] in the table), it's just that the values (SiteFieldValue) are different for each site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might get you started.  I've broken it up into steps but they can be chained quite easily.

```
#Get all the objects you'll need. You can filter as appropriate, say by site__name). 
qs = SiteFieldValue.objects.select_related('site', 'field')
#lets keep things simple and only get the values we want
qs_values = qs.values('site__name','field__name','value')
#qs_values is a queryset. For ease of manipulation, let's make it a list
qs_list = list(qs_values)
#set up a final dict
final_dict = {}
# create the keys (sites) and values so they are all grouped
for site in qs_list:
    #create the sub_dic for the fields if not already created
    if site['site__name'] not in final_dict:
        final_dict[site['site__name']] = {}
        final_dict[site['site__name']][site['name']] = site['site__name']
    final_dict[site['site__name']][site['field__name']] = site['value']
#now lets convert our dict of dicts into a list of dicts
# for use as per table2 docs
data = []
for site in final_dict:
    data.append(final_dict[site])
```

Now you have a list of dicts eg,
[{'name':site__name, 'col1name':value...] and can add it as shown in the [table2 docs](https://django-tables2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pages/table-data.html#list-of-dicts)

Comment: This seems nice and such, but my main problem was as of WHERE to put this code in the SiteListTable class. I tried to play with it many different ways, to use the `record` param, or alter some init. I'm good writing code, I'm just new to django and python shenanigans.

Comment: Fair enough.  I've tweaked my code to make it output a list of dicts as shown in the table2 docs, which should hopefully make implementation much less fiddly